# What are the most known examples of weighed voting that are practiced in democratic countries?

Tags: voting-systems, egalitarianism

From [Yannis' answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/735/101) to [What are the reasons against plural voting?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/667/what-are-the-reasons-against-plural-voting):

> ...similarly to how **forms of weighted voting** are not generally considered undemocratic and **are practiced and widely accepted in several democratic countries** and institutions.

**Question:** What are the most known examples of weighed voting that are practiced in democratic countries?

Comment: Do you mean proportional voting system?

Comment: Related: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/666/are-there-modern-examples-of-plural-voting

Comment: In 2003, then Austrian Minister of Economy Martin Bartenstein proposed a family voting scheme, whereby parents (the father? the mother?) would receive one extra vote for each of their children. Bartenstein is a member of the conservative party. The proposal went nowhere. This also holds for a similar initiative ([Familienwahlrecht](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familienwahlrecht)) in Germany.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Weighted voting is, simply put, a collective decision making process where votes are explicitly assigned unequal weights. It's actually a quite common approach in international bodies, notably followed in one form or another by:

- The European Parliament (degressive proportionality),
- The European Council (qualified majority voting),
- The International Monetary Fund,
- UN's Security Council.

A less obvious example is proportional representation. [Several countries that follow the approach for national elections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_representation#List_of_countries_using_proportional_representation) also employ minimum election thresholds and/or plurality bonuses, to avoid extreme fragmentation and maximize the chance of electing a strong government respectively. Both are weighted voting elements, and adding a bit of history to the mix creates complex examples, like Cyprus:

- 56 members of the House of Representatives are elected by proportional representation,
- 24 seats are allocated to the Turkish community (but remain vacant since 1964), and
- 3 seats are allocated to the Armenian, Latin and Maronite minorities.

Moving on, a perhaps more clear cut example on a national level is [single transferable vote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote), the approach followed in Ireland, Northern Ireland, Malta, Australia (for electing the Senate), India (by state legislatures), and... Stack Exchange community moderator elections ;)

Lastly, the US Electorate College is a prime example of weighted voting, disproportionally favouring the less populous states.

Comment: Didn't we arrive at a consensus that SE is a tyranny, not a democracy? :)))))  +1

Comment: @DVK The democracy is the tyranny of the majority, so they are both tyrannies